# sun.awt.image.ImageFormatException: Unsupported JPEG data precision 12

Tags: java, jpeg, java-io

I have a buffer that contains a 12-bit jpeg.
Using Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(...)

I get the following error:

sun.awt.image.ImageFormatException: Unsupported JPEG data precision 12
 at
sun.awt.image.JPEGImageDecoder.produceImage(JPEGImageDecoder.java:137)
 at
sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:265)

at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:151)
 at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:127)

Is there anyway to overcome this problem? FYI, Am using Java 1.4.19 version.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seriously, use a modern version of Java or make sure - wherever the image is coming from - that its format is compatible with what was available back in 2003. Even if there is an external library that supports this, it would probably not work with your version of Java.

Comment: Thanks @RealSkeptic. I should not use other than 1.4.19 version. Are there any plugins that will support this functionality?

Comment: Whoever tells you to use nothing else but 1.4.19 might act quite irresponsibly. Who knows what security issues are dormant in such an ancient version.